# Color of the fonts in my remote terminal screen when using VI in linux

Tags: linux, remote, vi, putty

I notice one of my linux remote login window shows color in VI editor interface but another window doesn't show color. These 2 windows are remotely connected to 2 different server IP addresses.

[image: Screenshots]

May I know why and how to change the color of the VI screen? I am using Putty on Windows 7 to remotely access the linux server.

Comment: Have you checked the settings in your PuTTY program? Maybe the settings are different for each login. I know you can change the color in PuTTY.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your TERM in both to the same thing.  If you use screen, those should be screen-256color-bce and if your terminal (urxvt for example) support 256 colours, you will get them.  Note that vim requires `set t_Co=256` in your ~/.vimrc to work properly.

I am assuming that you *want* colour to appear in all vi/vim windows.  If not, just change your terminal (putty) to be black and white.  You will then see no colours whatsoever.

Comment: Vim does not need explicit setting of the terminal's coloring capabilities if termcap or terminfo is set up correctly. That's what those are for. Setting t_Co=256 may actually be harmful when you run with a terminal that supports only 8 or 88 colors.

Comment: @user112553: Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: i am NOT using VIM and I am using VI only. Could you give more hints on this termcap or terminfo thing?

Comment: @Xianlin: As far as I know vi does not do colour highlighting.  As for termcap/terminfo, [this page](http://www.robmeerman.co.uk/unix/256colours) should give you some information.

Comment: I think probably when I type "vi" in the second terminal the linux (ubuntu) actually is using vim program for me because I may installed vim unconsciously on the second server...

Answer (score 1):

By default (at least on Fedora and other Redhat derivitives) vim-enhanced is installed and it adds a file /etc/profile.d/vim.sh

```
alias vi=vim
```

So in your .bashrc or manually you can unalias vi and you'll get the uncolored vi interface you expect. I put the following in my standard bashrc

```
unalias vi 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu but thank you and I learned something new...

Answer (score 1):

Using PuTTy , I unchecked the setting 'Allow terminal to specify ANSI colours' Under the Window=>Colours section. That did the trick without changing the background/foreground settings